# Emscripten with module loaders

Tags: javascript, module, emscripten

I'm trying to use Emscripten to turn a C library into a portable JavaScript module, that will be loaded by an AMD (such as Require.JS) and provide access to its functions and things:

```
require("vendor/mylib.js", function(mylib) {
    mylib.function1();
});
```

However, I've seen that Emscripten pollutes the global namespace with lots of variables, which is against the premise that modules should be independent and not collide with other loaded modules.

So the question is: **What's the best way to use Emscrpiten with AMDs?**

Is there a way I can tell Emscripten to not leak anything to `global`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 command line options from the [emcc docs](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html) that can help, `--pre-js <file>` and `--post-js <file>`. They allow you to wrap the generated code, and so allows you to integrate with AMDs.

For example, you could have a prefix file of

```
// prefix.js
define(function() {
  return function(Module) {
```

and a postfix file of

```
// postfix.js
  };
});
```

which you would compile outputting to `myModule.js` using something like

```
emcc --pre-js prefix.js --post-js postfix.js -o myModule.js myModule.cpp
```

and then `require` the module, using the RequireJS syntax:

```
require(['myModule'], function(myModule) {
  myModule({... Module definition object ...});
});
```

A fuller example, setting a canvas element in the module definition object follows. I'm also including the [domReady plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#domReady) to be able to grab elements when the DOM is ready.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(['domReady', 'myModule'], function(domReady, myModule) {
        domReady(function() {
          myModule({
            canvas: document.getElementById('canvas_1')
          });
          myModule({
            canvas: document.getElementById('canvas_2')
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas_1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_2"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

This then not only preserves the global namespace as you requested, but also allows you to have more than one Emscripten-powered canvas element in the page at once, if you need to.

The above HTML page can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/8jE3uLwrlszQuHbixU68?p=preview . It loads a C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;

int main() {
  cerr << "In C++ main function";
}
```

If you load the Plunker, then you should see "In C++ main function" twice, once for each loaded module.

If you need access to the Module object amended by Emscripten, say to call exposed library functions, you can do something like the following, waiting for all dependencies that Emscripten itself loads using the `monitorRunDependencies` option:

```
require(['myModule'], function(myModule) {
  var moduleDef = {
    monitorRunDependencies: function(numberOfDependenciesRemaining) {
      if (numberOfDependenciesRemaining) return;
      // At this point we can call functions added to moduleDef
      // such as cwrap or ccall
    }
  }
  myModule(moduleDef);
});
```

Comment: Very interesting, didn't think of using `--pre-js` and `--post-js` together like that... But I inspected that Plunk and the `Module` object is present in the global namespace. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @jmendeth I suspect I created it using what is an older version of Emscripten. Recent versions that include the commit at https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/commit/746230f45557868a91741553bf12cb17a3a95628 I think won't put the `Module` object in the global namespace

Comment: As per this [FAQ answer](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#can-i-use-multiple-emscripten-compiled-programs-on-one-web-page), Emscripten now has `MODULARIZE` and `EXPORT_NAME` compilation flags, which look promising...