# Changing the default namespace 'Module' in emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I am using emscripten to provide Javascript bindings for some libraries. Emsripten packages the code into a namespace (global var), called 'Module'.

I want to change the naming so that I can use a name that reflects what the library is used for, and also to prevent variable name collisions further down the line, as I write bindings for other libraries.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation, that shows how to do this. Does anyone know how I can change the default namespace used by emscripten?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change the [`EXPORT_NAME`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.32.2/src/settings.js#L463) setting from the default of `Module`. You can do this on the command line as an options to `emcc`:

```
emcc -s EXPORT_NAME="'MyEmscriptenModule'" <other options...>
```

and then the module will be available on the global scope by whatever name you specified:

```
window.MyEmscriptenModule == {...}
```

Note that if you set the [`MODULARIZE`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.32.2/src/settings.js#L413) setting to be 1, then whatever is set as `EXPORT_NAME` will be created as a function in the global scope that you must call to initialise the module. You can pass a settings object to this function, and it will return the module instance back:

```
var myModuleInstance = window.MyEmscriptenModule({noInitialRun: true});
```

If you're using some a module loader, such as RequireJS, and don't want to add anything to the global namespace at all, an alternative is to use the  `--pre-js <file>` and `--post-js <file>` options to wrap the final Javascript, as in [this answer to a question on Emscripten with module loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29332498/1319998).

Comment: +1 for link back to the **relevant parts** in the documentation. I don't know why I missed that the first ime round. Note to self: RTFM **carefully**

Comment: When I use `EXPORT_NAME=Lib` I always get back an error like: `NameError: name 'Lib' is not defined`. Is there something I need to do extra beyond just setting this option?

Comment: Oh I actually need `EXPORT_NAME="'Lib'"`, the extra single quotes are important!

Comment: Also wanted to point out that `noInitialRun` means not running `main` immediately, it does not mean not running `run` which is Emscripten's program startup initialisation.

Comment: **NOTE** One may be interested in [the `-s MODULARIZE=1` option](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/6dc4ac5f9e4d8484e273e4dcc554f809738cedd6/src/settings.js#L539-L563) as well. It does not pollute the global scope, exposes only the module instantiation function with a name specified with the `-s EXPORT_NAME="'……'"` option: `const module_object = EXPORT_NAME();`.

Comment: For me EXPORT_NAME only works if I use MODULARIZE or MODULARIZE_INSTANCE together with it.

Comment: idk but i had to add `-s MODULARIZE=1` in order for EXPORT_NAME to work; however, i then had to use `new Lib()`